# Handshake error in Websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, chat

I am done with server coding of a chat application.I am able to send response to a server and retrieve it.Now i am doing client side coding.

**Here is my first file**

```
      public class Client
       {
      public static void main(String ar[]) throws URISyntaxException, DeploymentException, IOException
        {     
      ChatRoomClientEndPoint chatroomClientEndPoint = new ChatRoomClientEndPoint();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("enter your username");
    String message = null;
    while(true)
    {
        message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    chatroomClientEndPoint.sendMessage(message);
    }
        }   
            }
```

**Here is my second file**

```
     @ClientEndpoint
     public class ChatRoomClientEndPoint 
     {
     Session session = null;
     public ChatRoomClientEndPoint() throws URISyntaxException, DeploymentException, IOException
      {
    URI uRI = new URI("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketPrj01/ServerEndPointDemo");
    ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().connectToServer(this,uRI);
       }
      @OnOpen
      public void processOpen(Session session)
      {
this.session = session;
      }
      @OnMessage
      public void processMessage(String message)
     {
System.out.println(Json.createReader( new               StringReader(message)).readObject().getString("message"));
     }
     public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException
     {
session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    }
```

I am using netbeans and ServerEndPointDemo is in another project named WebSocketPrj01 in netbeans.When i run Client class it gives following exception

> Exception in thread "main" javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.